# ¿Porque no estoy comparando bien mis dos Strings?

Tags: java

Hola he echo un mini tres en raya para practicar el tema de la POO. Pero me surge un error, no se si es a la hora de comparar los Strings en el método o compararlos en el main.

Método de la clase tres_en_raya:

```
// Metodo que nos permitira elegir quien comienza.

    public void setComienza(String respuesta) {

        this.respuesta = respuesta;

        if (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Yo")) {

            turnoPersona = true;

            esTurnoPrimero = true;

        } else if (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("IA")) {

            turnoPersona = false;
            esTurnoPrimero = false;

        } else {

        }
    }
```

Este método me devuelve el valor de resultado:

```
    public String getRespuesta() {

        return respuesta;

    }
```

Y así es como lo pongo en el método main, creo que se para compararse bien se hace con el método equals, pero para saber si es diferente no se cual método aplicar.

```
do {

        juego.setComienza(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Quien quieres que empieze?"));

        } while (juego.getRespuesta() != "Yo" || juego.getRespuesta() != "IA");

        if (juego.getComienza() == true) {

            while (juego.getGanar() == false || juego.getEmpate() == false) {

                juego.setJugada(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la fila")), Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce la columna")));

                System.out.println(juego.getImprimrTabla());

                juego.setTurnoRobot();

                juego.setFichaIA();

                System.out.println(juego.getImprimrTabla());
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para comparar dos String, se utiliza el método equals, porque String es una clase y no un tipo básico(int, char, etc).
Por tanto, para comparar dos objetos de tipo String, se debe utilizar un método que compare el valor en texto asignado a dicho objeto.

Para comparar si dos String son "diferentes", utiliza la misma función equals sobre objetos de tipo String, pero con el operador de negación "!":

```
String var1 = "hola";
String var2 = "adios";
if ( ! var1.equals(var2) ) //Si no son iguales
```

Comment: Muchas grácias no sabia que ese operador existía.

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar equals para comparar Strings, en todo caso, equalsIgnoreCase

```
 String respuesta = "HOLA";
 respuesta.equals("HOLA");              <----- true
 respuesta.equals("hola");              <----- false
 respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("HOLA");    <----- true
 respuesta equalsIgnoreCase("hola");    <----- true
```

Espero que te sirva la explicación